# how do I get NSSortDescriptors to work in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nssortdescriptor

I am struggling to get NSSortDescriptors to work on my mac tables.
    I did a quick proof of concept below and it still shows the same error:

> Error ProofSortDescriptors[19446:1951711] Failed to set
>   (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow):
>   [<_SwiftValue 0x60400007c180> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key name. ( name is the name of
>   the property of the struct)

Could it be to do with the change in way that Swift 4 bridges Objective C?

would be great to get this working on Mac Swift

Here is my attempt:

```
import Cocoa
struct Customer {
    var name:String
    var value:Int
}
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cust1 = Customer(name: "bob", value: 100)
        let cust2 = Customer(name: "cat", value: 200)
        let cust3 = Customer(name: "dog", value: 300)

        var custcol = [cust2, cust3, cust1]
        let descrip = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        let sorted = (custcol as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [descrip])
        var sortedCustomers = sorted as? [Customer]
        print(sortedCustomers!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a normal `NSSortDescriptor` with a Swift `struct`.

The normal `NSSortDescriptor`'s `compareObject:toObject:` method uses “key-value coding” to access the properties of the objects. Key-value coding only works with instances of `NSObject` (including instances of subclasses of `NSObject`). Swift `struct`s are not subclasses of `NSObject` (or even classes at all).

Since you're using sort descriptors because that's what `NSTableView` uses to sort rows, the simplest solution is just to change your model object type from a `struct` to a `class` that subclasses `NSObject`. Then declare each sortable property `@objc`.

Comment: Interesting - thanks Rob. I tried the class thing - but it gave me the same error.  I didn't realise you had to annotate each property you wanted to sort by.  ( Where is this documented) - btw that worked.  Do you want to add the code in and will mark it correct. 
```class Customer:NSObject {
   @objc var name:String
    @objc var value:Int
}```

Comment: @MobileBloke You can use `@objcMembers` in Swift 4 to annotate all.

Answer (score 3):

swift 4

For sorting custom class array using NSSortDescriptors in swift 4, you need to declare class as below.

```
@objcMembers class Customer:NSObject {
    var name:String!
    var value:Int!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a particular reason, you should avoid Objective-C relics in Swift code. Bridging back and forth between NSArray is a sign there might be a better, Swifty way of solving the problem.

```
let sortedCustomers = customers.sorted(by: { $0.name.compare($1.name) == .orderedAscending })
```

Comment: So just abandon sort descriptors ?

Comment: Yes. Do you have an actual reason for wanting to use them? It's extra work to make an Objective-C solution to a Swift problem.

Comment: In the table api on Mac OS X when you click a header it changes the sort descriptor and gives you the updated one - I would need to convert the result to swift syntax if I want to follow your suggestion and keep track of sort descriptors outside of Mac api

Comment: What table api?

Comment: `NSTableView` tracks which column headers the user has clicked on, and provides a [`sortDescriptors`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1534198-sortdescriptors) property to sort the table rows based on those clicks.

Comment: Hopefully Apple will update it in the next release.  I think this is just a bit of legacy thats left.

Comment: There are new initializers which take `#keyPath` but there is probably nothing more they can do now.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the code I needed to get this working without changing the `NSSortDescriptor`. To get `Customer` KVC compliant, it needs to be a `class` derived from `NSObject` and any KVC compliant properties need to be marked with `@objc`.

```
class Customer: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String
    var value: Int

    init(name: String, value: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

---

A Swiftier way of doing this is implement `Comparable`

```
struct Customer {
    var name: String
    var value: Int
}

extension Customer: Comparable {
    static func ==(lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    static func <(lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }
}

class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cust1 = Customer(name: "bob", value: 100)
        let cust2 = Customer(name: "cat", value: 200)
        let cust3 = Customer(name: "dog", value: 300)

        let custcol = [cust2, cust3, cust1]
        let sortedCustomers = custcol.sorted()
        print(sortedCustomers)
    }
}
```

or mutate customers directly.

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cust1 = Customer(name: "bob", value: 100)
        let cust2 = Customer(name: "cat", value: 200)
        let cust3 = Customer(name: "dog", value: 300)

        var customers = [cust2, cust3, cust1]
        customers.sort()
        print(customers)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with comparable is that it's not so easy to chain comparisons.

Comment: @Sulthan There are relatively simple solutions for chaining comparisons in Swift. It was not part of the question.

Comment: Nice approach - and thanks for the detail @JefferyThomas.

Comment: The value behind sort descriptors is that they are scalable - and can be applied to different properties using a single API .  The swift mechanisms all seem to work to a single implementation - ie sorting by only specific property which is coded into comparable but don't allow  easily allowsorting by other  individual specific properties without major code.  NS Sort descriptors (for now) seem like the best and simplest approach - even if you have to mangle your structs with legacy code.. Hope they fix in next version.